# C - pthread_create - Clang GCC difference

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, clang

Passing the argument to pthread_create with clang (3.6.1) and gcc (5.1.0) brings different results for a strange case, illustrated here:

```
pthread_t spawn_bserver_thread(uint16_t portno)
{   
    pthread_t tid;
    int32_t sockfd = create_bserver(portno);
    set_nonblocking(sockfd);

    exit_ncurses();
    printf("%d\n", sockfd);

    if(pthread_create(&tid, NULL, bserver_thread, &sockfd) != 0)
        error("pthread_create");

    return tid;
}
```

and bserver_thread:

```
static void * bserver_thread(void *arg)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int32_t*)arg);
    exit(1);
    ...
}
```

With gcc it prints the same number, but not with clang. (my typical result is 4 and 4 with gcc but 4 then 32767 with clang). Am I doing something wrong here?

Here are the CFLAGS if it can change anything: -Wall -Wextra -ggdb

Comment: Are you certain that you call `exit` in the thread function? Because that will exit the whole process.

Comment: I don't call it normally, it's to debug this problem. And I don't think it can affects the outcome of the the printfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have no control over when the thread starts to run, so the `spawn_bserver_thread` function may exit before the thread function starts, meaning the `sockfd` variable goes out of scope and the pointer argument to the `bserver_thread` function is no longer valid.